# How to restore submitted SVN project versions after the folder structure has been changed?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, directory

During the development of the small project I used SVN and Tortoise. Later on I decided to change the directory hierarchy under my project's folder. The root project folder contained to much subfolders so I made a new one and put all the folders I wanted to group in it. After that I submitted changes. Actually I thought that the new directory tree was going to be updated whithin SVN repository in accordance with local changes. But something went wrong and all the versions in SVN-client disappeared. I found for now that there are move and relocate commands to SVN and I probably should use them.

The questions are why is that happen and how to restore my repository?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your working copy, do a Show Log on your project root, select the bad commit, and choose "revert changes from this revision". This will make your working copy as before the bad commit. Redo the changes correctly, and then commit.

If there has been multiple bad commits, then find the latest good commit, and choose "Revert to this revision". Redo the changes correctly, and then commit.